# Converting array of HahMap into json object in servlet and display it in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I want to fetch all table rows and add them into array of hashmap then convert them into json object to send to jsp page using ajax and jquery. I'm having problem in displaying the contents in jsp page. 
I have managed to write the below code and need help to correct/improve it and I'm confused how to display it in jsp page. I'm a beginner in jquery and json.

```
   try {
       String res = request.getParameter("hello");
       String user = "";
       String pass = "";
       String port = "";
       String dbname = "";
       String host = "";
       String driver = "oracle.dbc.driver.OracleDriver";
       Connection con;
       PreparedStatement ps;
       ResultSet rs;
       String json = null;
       String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+host+":"+port+":"+dbname;

       Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
       List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

       try{
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee");

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                map.put("name", rs.getString(1));
                map.put("id", rs.getString(2));
                map.put("salary",rs.getString(3));
                list.add(map);
            }                
            json = new Gson().toJson(list);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
       }catch(Exception e){               
       }


    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
```

index.jsp

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#push").click(function(){
               var value = $("#t").val();
               $.post('jsonServlet',{hello:value},function(data){

             //     ??
              //    ??
              //    ??

               });
            });            
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body  style="position: absolute;min-height: 700px;min-width: 1300px">
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="PushMe" id="push">
        <input type="text" id="t" value="my data">
        <div style="position: absolute;height: 50%;width: 60%;" id="myDiv">

        </div>
    </form>        
</body>
```

Need help in jsp page to display the contents of hash map in div...
Later I will change the div with text boxes to store individual column values so that user can modify the contents of table and again update the table rows.

Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a map looks ew, make a class instead:

```
class Person{
    public final String name;
    public final String id;
    public final String salary;
    public Person(String name, String id, String salary){
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
        this.salary=salary;
    }
}
```

Does not need to be a public class, you may put it in your servlet java file. Gson knows how to serialize classes to json.

Read from database:

```
while(rs.next()){
    list.add(new Person(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)));
}
```

In your javascript something like this:

```
$.post(
    'jsonServlet', // <- may screw up path here
    { hello: value },
    function(data){
        var table = '<table>';
        for(var i = data.length, l = data.length; i>0; i--){
            // one of over 9000 ways to make js loops work faster
            var person = data[l-i]; // <- this one also does not screw up order
            var row = '<tr>';
            row +='<td>'+person.name+'</td>';
            row +='<td>'+person.id+'</td>';
            row +='<td>'+person.salary+'</td>';
            row +='</tr>';
            table += row;
        }
        table += '</table>';
        $('#myDiv').html(table);
    },
    'json'
);
```

You may want to actually prepare the table beforehand somewhere in your jsp, maybe in a hidden div and use it as a template.

Comment: About that for() design: as of now javascript downwards loops are some hundreds times faster than forward loops, consistently across all browsers. Caching array's length has almost no effect whatsoever. http://jsperf.com/loopy-arrays/3

Comment: hello sir i know i marked it as solved, but still there is an issue. i  am not getting the values from servlet in my jsp. not even a simple string. Is there any problem with my gson() method or with ther url pattern in ajax call ?

Comment: Try inspecting what your server responds in your browser dev tools > network console. If it's some 404 error (and you actually see full url is wrong), then its url. If it's empty response or 500 internal with correct request headers then your java is wrong. I wouldn't try to guess.